# What is the strongest weapon in Kid Icarus: Uprising?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

I want to know the strongest weapon is in *Kid Icarus: Uprising*. My guess would have to be either the Midnight Palm, the Cutter Palm, the Ninja Palm, the Samurai Blade or the Ogre Club.

Answer (score 4):

There is no one strongest weapon. Different weapons are stronger in certain aspects though.

I've been working on recording [statistics for each weapon in the game on Icaruspedia](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Weapon), so you can view specific values there.

Here are some of the highlights:

- The [Ogre Club](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Ogre_Club) has the highest melee damage
- The [Magnus Club](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Magnus_Club) has the second highest melee damage, but also has the shortest range of any weapon.
- The [Flintlock Staff](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Flintlock_Staff) has the highest damage at a long distance, but the weakest melee damage. It also has the fastest projectiles.
- The [Earthmaul Club](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Earthmaul_Club) has the longest range in the game, followed by the [Laser Staff](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Laser_Staff).
- [Claws](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Claws) typically have the highest rate of fire, but certain [blades](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Blade) and [palms](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Palm) also have rapid fire.
- [Cannons](http://www.kidicaruswiki.org/Cannon)' charged shots can often hit multiple foes, making their total damage against multiple foes higher than single-target weapons with higher damage.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solidified "best weapon" other than "Daybreak" which is only in multiplayer and is a on use OHKO weapon. The best weapon depends on your play style.

- If you are good with homing, but is also good with melee,use bows. Bows gain more power the farther the shot travels to hit the target within range if that makes any sense. Some bows have a number of shots per second wise, bad continuous fire, such as the "Palutena Bow" that rely on dash, charged, and dash charged shots. On the other hand, some bows have ridiculous homing with charged shots, but sacrifice the usual homing in continuous fire for extremely fast and long periods of semi-weak shots. An example of that kind of bow is the "Phosphora Bow". The rule of distance=power still applies for these bows too.
- If you are good with fast movements and dodging, along with extremely fast rapid fire, but no homing, and good melee combos, then claws are for you. Claws, while lacking the range of bows and staffs, make up for it in speed, evasiveness, and melee, and powerful range depending on what type of claw. All claws make you faster, and more lightweight and prone to knock-back. But, play with them right and you will destroy everything.
- Arms are weapons that have horrible range (as in distance, their shots can potentially be extremely powerful) but make up for it in good melee attacks and combos. Arms are the jack-of-all-trades weapon, prone to being anything depending on the user and its powers and attributes.
- Staffs are the sniper weapon. While most staffs are garbage in melee, some, such as the "Orb Staff" are inclined towards melee and range. Depending on if you are more of a sniping type or both melee and sniping, you might want to consider this weapon class.
- Cannons are the most powerful ranged weapon. Their shots bounce off of other surfaces, and can hit multiple targets due to the fact that it can explode. You take a bit of recoil sometimes however. Cannons also have an ability for decent melee. Also, cannon make you very slow. So if you are the slow, but powerful type, this is your weapon class.
- Clubs on the other hand are the exact opposite of cannons. Clubs are strictly for melee. They do not have rapid fire, only charged shots. Catch is though, the charged shots are extremely powerful when they hit. Clubs also slow you down considerably. It is tricky to use, but can be very effective.
- Blades are also jack of all trades, but this time, they have equal range and melee ability. As you start out with a blade, you already know how they handle.
- Palms are an almost no-weight weapon. They have good homing, and are good for melee, but usually have a shorter continuous fire range. They can be fast or slow. Depending on if you prefer melee over ranged but want to keep range in case, palms are for you.
- Orbitars do not weigh anything, and is a ranged based weapon that can perform melee poorly or very well depending on the type of orbitar.

Note that all of the above may vary due to the particular weapon and it's attributes and powers.

Answer (score 0):

Statistically, clubs do the most damage without modifiers. HOWEVER, almost any weapon can be stronger than Clubs if it has the right modifiers.

The "strongest" weapon depends largely on your play style. My favorite is my Palutena Bow, due to speed and range. However, if you prefer to move quickly, Claws are the way to go (the Brawler Claws provide the highest movement speed without any modifiers), and by fusing to them with weapons with higher damage output modifiers, you increase the damage output of the Claws through the passing of the modifiers.

Comment: The Magnus Club is not the strongest at long ranged or melee damage. Fists aren't a weapon type (although I'm guessing you mean Claws). You can't modify the inherent attributes of a weapon through fusion, only modifiers and damage rating. Also you can never fuse a weapon to that same type of weapon in a single fusion.

Comment: I never said that you could modify the inherent attributes. The Magnus Club does have the most potential for melee as far as I am aware, AND I never said that it would take a single fusion. I meant to say that it would take a while, but it really isn't necessary as a simple Google search would have given the fusion mechanics.

Comment: Oh ok, it sounded like that was what you were saying in the middle paragraph. I recommend editing "Fists" to "Claws" and possibly making what you meant about fusion a little clearer. The site will let me change my vote if it's edited too.

Comment: I probably do best with the palms and blades...

Answer (score 0):

The Samurai Blade and the Aurum Palm are the strongest weapons due to the fact that the Samurai Blade has a quick melee combo attack rate.The Aurum Palm has the quickest charge shot which fires a charge shot per sec.

Answer (score 0):

Trust me when I say this: The best weapons in Kid Icarus Uprising is the Samurai Blade and the Lancer Staff. If these weapons are too slow or whatever I suggest the following: Their are six slots for modifiers so I suggest these:

Lancer Staff: Overall Defense+8, Shot Homing+8, Stamina+8, Evasion+8, In-Peril Attack Boost+8, Speed+6

Samurai Blade: Overall Defense+8, Dash Cont Fire+8, Stamina+8, Evasion+8, In-Peril Attack Boost+8, Speed+6

*Note: Although these are hard to get they are the sure key to victory :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange. Thank you for your answer; however, as it currently is the main crux of your answer seems more opinion than actual fact. Please consider editing your answer with a better explanation why those two weapons are superior to everything else in your opinion. Thanks!

Comment: Those are impossible stats.

Answer (score 0):

Aurum palm is fast charged, aurum blade is pretty sweet, aurum orbitars and bow...

Yeah, I use aurum stuff a lot.

But good non-aurum gear is: wolf claws, have decent speed and set fire to enemies very commonly.

Laser staff: second best range and very powerful, not too shabby charge time, ok melee.

Beam claws: no additional effect (other then modifiers), but pretty good all around.

Stealth claws: mostly good for dark VS light, free for all is impossible to hide from all the others, and the invisible shots make it perfect for RKO out of nowhere moments.

Anyhow, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Well to be vauge the guardian oribitars have an ability only one other weapon has. It ranks 2/12 in the craft list so any 1+1 should do the trick. Guardian orbitars have charge shots that stay put rather than traveling. This makes it a great shot nullifier, even w/o the shot cancellation modifier. The back charge shot by far outranks most weapons in strength. It doesn't dicipate when hit. It's like a cannon but with more attack area. A plus 8 speed modifier would make you unstoppable. Grinding treasure and hearts in ch: 24 is a great method to buy weapons. Guardian orbitars are also well versed melee weapons. If given the right modifiers you'd be a god.

Answer (score -1):

Best clubs: Magnus, Hewdraw and Capricorn
Best orbitars: Eyetrack, Arurum, Fairy and Gemini.
Best arms: Compact, Kraken and Taurus
Best palms: Ninja, Cutter, and Violet
Best bows: Aurum, Angel, and Phosphora
Best claws: Tiger, Brawler and Raptor
Best blades: Samurai, Aurum and Gaol (maybe)
Best staffs: Rose, Thanatos and Dark Pit
Best cannons: Doom and Predator